# tfpdf php bangali language and new lines

Tags: php, pdf

I have a little issue when use tcpdf with bengali language (all other language work well). I found Bengali font Nikosh.ttf (tried another one but with only Bengal issue the same) each symbol on new line but in text it in one line. How to fix this? Need text to display as it was written.

```
$pdf = new tFPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->AddFont('Nikosh','','Nikosh.ttf',true);
$pdf->SetFont('Nikosh','',14);

$txt = file_get_contents('HelloWorld.txt');
$pdf->Write(8,$txt);

$pdf->Output();
```

HelloWorld.txt contains

```
English: Hello World
Bengali: দৃষ্টিতে স্বল্পসংখ্যক ছিলেন
```

what I get insted
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByCB3iOJZXTLQ1lubG16dlpaREU/view?usp=sharing
Thanks for help

Comment: Try stripping new line characters before writing to the file.

Comment: delete all \n\r\s but it still on new line

    $txt = preg_replace('/[\n\r\s]/', '', file_get_contents('HelloWorld.txt'));

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
<?php
require_once('tcpdf_include.php');

// create new PDF document 
$pdf = new  TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false); 

// remove default header/footer 
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false); 
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false); 

// set default monospaced font 
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED); 

// set margins 
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, 15, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT); 

// set auto page breaks 
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 15); 

// set image scale factor 
//$pdf->setImageScale(1); 

// add a page 
$pdf->AddPage(); 

$strBNFont = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('Nikosh.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32); 
$pdf->SetFont($strBNFont, '', 14, '', 'true'); 

//$pdf->SetFont('times', '', 8); 

$txt = "English: Hello World
Bengali: দৃষ্টিতে স্বল্পসংখ্যক ছিলেন "; 

$pdf->Write(0, $txt, '', 0, 'C', true, 0, false, false, 0); 

//Close and output PDF document 
//$pdf->Output($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . time() . '.pdf', 'F'); 
$pdf->Output();

//echo 'done';
```

Comment: Yes I know about tcpdf but it much bigger and little slower then tfpdf

Comment: And tcpdf also doesn't write it well as need